# Helm: wrong type for value; expected string; got []interface {} while adding a function from .tpl file to configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a configmap by using include function from my .tpl file.

configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: abc
  labels:
    app: abc
    chart: {{ $.Chart.Name }}-{{ $.Chart.Version | replace "+" "-" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  namespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}

data:
  pqr.conf: |
    {{ $config := fromYaml (include "yyz.agentConfig" .) }}
    {{- $config | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
```

_uuu.tpl has the agentConfig function.

```
{{/*
Config for the agent
The values can be overridden in .Values.agent.config
*/}}
{{- define "yyz.agentConfig" -}}
exporters:
  logs:
    uuu: {{ .Values.a.uuu | quote }}
    bnk: "${*****}"
    lqp: {{ .Values.a.lqp| quote }}
    qqq: {{ .Values.a.qqq | quote }}
    www: {{ .Values.a.www }}
    rrr: {{ .Values.a.rrr }}
{{ end }}
```

I am getting below error while running this. Can someone help me here?

```
Error: template: path/configmap.yaml:14:28: executing "path/configmap.yaml" at <include "yyz.agentConfig" .>: error calling include: template: path/_uuu.tpl:90:45: executing "yyz.agentConfig" at <8>: wrong type for value; expected string; got []interface {}
```

Comment: What is in `.Values.a`?  Which specific line is causing the problem?  The overall structure of this seems fine; I might not round-trip `include | fromYaml | toYaml` but I don't think this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: value of a is url like a = https://......com 
I have not added any quotes over here
Line 8 is .Values.a